# copyFile from two lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell.

My objective is to copy files from one directory to other directory.

So far what I have:

I have two lists contain full path file names

```
list1 = ["file1", "file2" ...]
list2 = ["new name1", "new name2"...]
```

I want to use

```
copyFile::FilePath->FilePath->IO()
```

to copy files from list1 to list2

Note: list2 contains all new full path file names

I know

```
zipWith(a->b->c)->[a]->[b]->[c]
```

and I try to

```
zipWith(copyFile) list1 list2
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Since

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

and

```
System.Directory.copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
```

if you `zip` with `copyFile`, you get:

```
zipWith copyFile :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath] -> [IO ()]
```

that is, given two lists of file paths, you get a list of actions in which each action copies a file. You can evaluate such list of actions using `sequence_`:

```
sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

(in this case, `sequence_ :: [IO ()] -> IO ()`).

Thus, something like

```
sequence_ (zipWith copyFile ["foo", "bar"] ["new_foo", "new_bar"])
```

would work for you.

EDIT: Even better, as suggested by Daniel Wagner, use `Control.Monad.zipWithM_` (`zipWithM_ copyFile [...] [...]`).

Comment: `Control.Monad` also offers `zipWithM` and `zipWithM_`.

Answer (score 0):

`copyFile` is a monadic action so you cannot use `zipWith` on it, here is what you can do:

```
mapM_ (uncurry copyFile) $ zip list1 list2
```

note `mapM_`'s type signature:

```
λ> :t mapM_
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```